# How to create a clone of my OS?

Tags: backup, cloning

Today I ran into a irrecoverable problem by accidentally formatting my ubuntu drive, In future I don't want to face these kinda problems, So how can I have a clone of my OS (I mean with all the software I installed) so that if i run into a problem I can just somehow use the clone to get back my OS ? BTW in another post someone mentioned Remastersys , but their website says that the software will no longer be available.

any related tips also might help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use default Ubuntu backup that comes with Ubuntu. Go to System settings -> Backup